# What is best approach for iPhone location tracking app in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, background-process

I'm trying to come up with the best possible approach for the location tracking iPhone application which tracks location in the background.

Background model is slightly different from the Android and Windows Phone platforms and I'm not sure how to achieve the best possible result.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to:

- periodically run a job in background even if my app is terminated
- during background job fetch current user location  during background
- job submit the location to my server using POST Http Request

Most of background approaches are not working for me because they requires the app not to be terminated. I want to submit location even if the app is terminated. I also don't care how often my background job will be executed by the system, once a minute,  once an hour or once a day. I need it as often as system allows me. I found the two possible solution:

1. Background Fetch
2. Remote Notification

The question is: Could I

- fetch the user location when iOS gives me an opportunity to perform
  my background job (I believe, yes, with "Location Updates" mode
  enabled, but I'm not sure)?
- submit a location to a backend server
  (not fetch but submit, using POST http method)?

Please, advise. 
Alternative solutions are appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding with definite answers. Discussions of high-level design concepts and best practices are more appropriate for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82990/228805) for more information.

Comment: if it is too broad why it generates votes and question/answer buzz? Please un-hold this topic. I have specific question, not abstract one

Comment: I don't see the connection. The fact that it has received votes (one of which was a downvote, BTW) and some responses is no indication whatsoever that it's appropriate for Stack Overflow. The measure of topicality is not whether the question is completely ignored by all readers. Also note that the Close Votes review was unanimous--not one person voted "Leave Open". I stand by my previous comment and the close vote: this is a design/discussion question, not a coding question, and belongs at http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Please read the linked meta post in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to use apple's core location api

it provides many ways to track the users location based on accuracy required or battery life considerations

you can register with the notification center about location information.... the phone will periodically launch your app under special conditions (it won't launch the full thing) so that you can update your data and app variables accordingly

this way it won't matter if the app is open or not

the two things you need to look into are notification center and the core location api

here is a link to the api reference
Core Location Framework Reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: is it about location fetching only? I have no issues with fetching the location. I'm trying to come up with the approach to perform it periodically in background without having my app in foreground or even background.

Comment: I just added something about using the notification center... if you register with the notification center the phone will launch your app under special conditions... If you look in the app delegate you'll notice that it has a place for when it launches with special options... Ive never done it myself but I know thats the best way to do it

Comment: core location will not work for me. My general goal is to keep updated backend even if app is terminated. Look: "If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the system doesn’t automatically restart your app when new location updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the delivery of location updates resumes"

Comment: You need to use the "Significant location change" notification https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8 This notification will be delivered if your app is terminated (although in 7.0 it won't be delivered if the user explicitly terminates your app - apparently this behaviour has changed in 7.1)

Comment: interesting! Will I be able to do a web request to submit received data?